# Does make an object from another class inside a method considered composition

Tags: java, composition

If I have this class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalc {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Scanner scan;

    public SimpleCalc() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
        this.x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
        this.y = scan.nextInt();
    }

}
```

This class uses composition concept because it has "scan" object from another class "Scanner".

But what if I declared the "scan" object inside a method like this:

```
public SimpleCalc() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
    this.x = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
    this.y = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Does that considered composition concept?

In another way: does composition concept applies to just classes or also applies to methods?

Comment: It applies to classes as an alternative to inheritance.

Comment: both cases are not considered composition, just having a reference to another type is not composition. If your class would be a `SpecialSanner` and provide a `nextInt` method which would with some custom logic delegate to the `Scanner` then you would speak of composition. `public class Person { String name; ... }` is no composition candidate, it just is a regular class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is, in the context of design pattern and specifically related to Composite Design Patter, then the short answer is NO.

As [GOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) has described:

> "Compose objects into tree structure to represent part-whole
>   hierarchies.Composite lets client treat individual objects and
>   compositions of objects uniformly".

So this doesn't apply for methods.

Comment: could you confirm this: if I make an object from another class inside a method that doesn't considered composition

Comment: By making an object, you are instantiating a class within the method. This is only a local reference to that object in your method. It is no on the class level. This is not a composite design in my opinion.